# Jquery Plugin not available inside a function?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to load longitude and latitude data into cookies using the following code:

```
$.cookie('test', 'test');
var test = true;

function PageLoaded() {
    if (test) {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success_handler, error_handler, {
                enableHighAccuracy: true
            });
            test = false;
        }
    }
}

function success_handler(position) {
    latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
    document.getElementById("tbLat").value = latitude;
    document.getElementById("tbLon").value = longitude;
    $.cookie('Latitude', latitude);
    $.cookie('Longitude', longitude);

}

function error_handler() {
    document.write('This browser does not support location awareness or you have declined to allow it to view your location.');
}
```

I am loading the JQuery.Cookie.js plugin. 
The first cookie "test" loads properly but the second two "Latitude & Longitude" throw an error that

> Object doesn't support property or method 'cookie'

Why is this?

Comment: In the middle of your `success_handler` you switch to standard dom `getElementById` calls. To stay consistent you should probably stick with jQuery, `$('#tbLat').... `

Comment: try `jQuery.cookie('Longitude', longitude);`

Comment: @mgraph: that won't have any effect.

Comment: FYI...I probably should have used a different name for the function than "PageLoaded" it is actually being triggered by an onclick.

Comment: is it reaching the jquery namespace? do other jquery functions work in that method enclosure? What does the stacktrace say? Can you just use simple strings (as opposed to latitude)?

Comment: It seems to be reaching the JQuery namespace. I have had ohter "plugins" that I have tried to call from there not work also.

Comment: And using simple strings in the calls doesn't make a difference inthis case.

Answer (score -2):

jQuery doesn't have a `cookie()` function. You forgot to include the cookie plugin - https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: I am loading the cookie plugin.

Comment: Ah, my bad. What is invoking `PageLoaded()`?

Comment: A Simple onclick event on a button.